# Python OpenCV DrawContours

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to create a program to decipher a specific type of captchas.

My approach is to split the captcha in distinct characters (always made of 5, small letters and numbers only) and store each character in a separate folder in order to have a database for training, then see how it will perform.

I run into a problem when trying to find the contours by using openCV.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('4n2gd.png')
imcopy = im.copy()
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(imcopy,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = cv2.medianBlur(imgray,5)
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

finimg = cv2.bitwise_not(th)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(finimg,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.imwrite('modified.png',im)
```

The initial image:
[image]

The image with drawn contours:
[image]

The thing is that I expect, the CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, to make rectangles around each set if black pixels, but rather it just functions the same as CHAIN_APPROX_NONE.

What should I do to modify this?

Comment: What you're looking for is a bounding box, rather than just a simplified contour. See [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html) OpenCV tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much